# display particular category products in empty search result page

Tags: magento-1.7, product-list, catalogsearch

In empty search result page, I need to display the product list of a particular category.  So, I have added the code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setCategoryId(5)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml()?>
```

in **catalogsearch/result.phtml**.  But this is not worked.

While check the flow, I have found that $this->getLayer() calls the catalogsearch in **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php**.  Can I change the layer as Catalog, if the search is empty.  If it is possible to change the layer, then how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down below code in your `result.phtml`

1. check weather search result contains result record more then 1.
2. If not write down following code...

   `$category_id=2;` // your category id here..

   ```
   $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(trim($category_id));

       foreach ($category->getProductCollection() as $product) {

       $product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
       echo $product->getData("name");

   }
   ```

Comment: I have also done in the same way as you explained.  But I want to get the results from changing the layer in List.php.

Comment: for that you have to write the above function in block of your custom module.. & in controller you have to call the same...